# Dynamically fetch value from hashmap during select spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a map defined with key value pair. While selecting column I for a dataframe I need to dynamically fetch column name as value from Map based on key provided like,

```
val map = HashMap("emp_id" -> "dept_id","emp_city" ->  "dept_city" );
val df1 = df.select($"$map.get($name)")
```

Here `name` will be key in map  and I need to get related value in expression above but it throws error. What could be problem here

Comment: "but it throws error" - please edit the post to show what the error is

Comment: It's probably just wrong use of string interpolation - expressions that are not mere variable names must be surrounded with curly brackets, i.e. `df.select($"${map.get(name)}")`

Comment: @TzachZohar : It works. Can you put it in comments. I will accept as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Tzach, the problem was with string interpolation- changing the  expression to `$"df.${map.get(name).mkString}"` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Just use `apply`:

```
f.select(map(name))
```